# Should I use copyFromRealm() for populating a Spinner?

Tags: android, realm

I have read a few answers and tutorials about when to use `copyFromRealm` but I am still unsure if my understanding is correct; which is, use `copyFromRealm` when you want to have untethered Objects (if you change them, nothing will change in Realm DB).

In my case I have a Spinner and I want to populate it with values from Realm:

```
Spinner mySpinner = ...;

List<MyObjects> myObjects = RealmInstance.getInstance().getRealm().where(MyObject.class).findAll();
myObjects = RealmInstance.getInstance().getRealm().copyFromRealm(myObjects); // do I need this here?

List<String> entries = new ArrayList<>();
for(MyObject t : myObjects)
    entries.add(t.getName() + " (" + t.getDesc() + ")");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, entries);

mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I think I don't need to copy the objects to an unmanaged list since I will not modify them and I am anyways copying the values to a separate array (`entries`).

Is my thinking right here?

Comment: I think, u're totally right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spinners, if you don't intend to change things directly, then you can use [RealmBaseAdapter](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/c4ec2e0df75aea24df2e67b2135909198f05a789/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.java), as long as you customize `getDropDownView`.

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView,
        @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
}
```